# How can a button display different results depending on radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that generates random first and last names upon button click. The code works fine but i'm looking to edit the function so that it checks the radio button selected and generate different names according to gender. Here is my code:

```js
// Create an array of first names
var firstNamem = ['Ragnar', 'Bjorn', 'Eric', 'Olaf', 'Ivar', 'Harald', 'Sigurd', ];
var firstnamef = ['Babbete','Babs','Astrid', 'Lachie','Lady','Lael','Bodil','Fridagertud']
var firstnameo = ['Alex','Evan','Esra','Finn','Gael','Dyre','Ronnie','Dale']
// Create an array of last names 
var lastName = ['Lodbrok', 'Ironside', 'Bloodaxe', 'the Boneless', 'War-Tooth', 'Foul-Fart', 'Troll-Buster'];

//Event listener
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        
    });
});

//Create function that will be called when the button is clicked
if(gender == 'male'){
function nameMe() { 
  var rfn = firstNamem[Math.floor((Math.random() * firstNamem.length))];
  var rln = lastName[Math.floor((Math.random() * lastName.length))];  
  document.getElementById('yourNameIs').textContent = rfn + " " + rln;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <title>Viking Gen</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Viking Name Generator</h1>
  <br/>
  <form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form> 
<br/>
<button onclick="nameMe()">My Name is</button> <span id="yourNameIs"></span>
```

Comment: what did you try? stackoverflow is here to help, but not to solve your homework

Comment: I tried adding another function nameMef() to generate names from the array firstnamef when the button is clicked with female radio button selection but that didn't work.

Comment: also tied adding an event listener, 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){

Comment: Great. Show what you tried so other people can try and fix it/explain what you did wrong and how to do it right :)

Comment: I apologize if I failed to follow rules or guidelines, here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XFc2j/89/

Comment: I updated your question with the code from the jsfiddle link

Comment: I added an answer based on your code in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Object Literal `names = {}` to store your values.

Than it's simple to do  `names.male[0]` or `names[gender][0]` where `gender` is the `value` of the `:checked` radio button that matches the `male` / `female` / `other` property of `names` Object:

```js
var names = {
  male:   ['Ragnar', 'Bjorn', 'Eric', 'Olaf', 'Ivar', 'Harald', 'Sigurd', ],
  female: ['Babbete','Babs','Astrid', 'Lachie','Lady','Lael','Bodil','Fridagertud'],
  other:  ['Alex','Evan','Esra','Finn','Gael','Dyre','Ronnie','Dale'],
  last:   ['Lodbrok', 'Ironside', 'Bloodaxe', 'the Boneless', 'War-Tooth', 'Foul-Fart', 'Troll-Buster']
};

function nameMe() {
  var gnd = document.querySelector("[name='gender']:checked").value;
  var rfn = names[gnd][Math.floor((Math.random() * names[gnd].length))];
  var rln = names.last[Math.floor((Math.random() * names.last.length))];  
  document.getElementById('yourNameIs').textContent = rfn + " " + rln;
}

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", nameMe);
```

```html
<label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male   </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">       Female </label>
<label> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other">        Other  </label>

<br>
<button id="generate">GENERATE</button> 

<br>
Your name is: <b id="yourNameIs"></b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the firstnames arrays inside an object with keys that match the value of the radio buttons.

Then, simply check which radio button is checked to get the correct firstnames array and pick a random firstname inside it.

```js
// Create an array of first names
const firstnames = {
  male: ['Ragnar', 'Bjorn', 'Eric', 'Olaf', 'Ivar', 'Harald', 'Sigurd'],
  female: ['Babbete', 'Babs', 'Astrid', 'Lachie', 'Lady', 'Lael', 'Bodil', 'Fridagertud'],
  other: ['Alex', 'Evan', 'Esra', 'Finn', 'Gael', 'Dyre', 'Ronnie', 'Dale']
}

// Create an array of last names 
const lastName = ['Lodbrok', 'Ironside', 'Bloodaxe', 'the Boneless', 'War-Tooth', 'Foul-Fart', 'Troll-Buster'];

function nameMe() {
  const gender = document.querySelector("[name='gender']:checked").value;
  const rfn = firstnames[gender][Math.floor((Math.random() * firstnames[gender].length))];
  const rln = lastName[Math.floor((Math.random() * lastName.length))];

  document.getElementById('yourNameIs').value = rfn + " " + rln;
}
```

```html
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" checked> Male<br>
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="female"> Female<br>
<input name="gender" type="radio" value="other"> Other <br>
<button onClick="nameMe()">Generate name</button>
<input id="yourNameIs"/>
```